# Update items in a ObservableCollection when Collection is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Question: How can I update all items within an ObservableCollection when the CollectionChanged-Event is raised?

I search a lot but not find any suitable question with an answer for this. Maybe I searched wrong or my code is crap at all... ;-)

Background:
I got a list of items from the user and need to check them in some criteria. One of the criteria is that one attribut needs to be gapless within the submitted items. This attribut is not directly visible to the user, so I cannot just throw him back to give me correct items. That is because I show him a Datagrid with the information which items are ok and which not.
Now he is be able to delete items by selecting them and press del (I cannot decide which one should be deleted) so that finally all items in the list a valid.
Because it can happend that now other items not valid anymore, I need to check every item again after the list changed.
Everything works fine until I delete something and then I got a "cannot change collection during CollectionChanged-Event"-error at the marked point.

My project contains a more complex code (and checks), but for simplicity I try to show some code as example.

Let us say I got a list of numbers from the user and every number needs to have an successor.
So I have class that take the Number and the information

```cs
public class Number() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public Number(int i)
        {
            digit = i;
            HasSuccessor = null;
        }

        private int digit;
        public int Digit { 
            get { return digit; }
            set { digit = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        private bool? hasSuccessor;
        public bool? HasSuccessor {
            get { return hasSuccessor; }
            set { hasSuccessor = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
            else PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

in my Viewmodel I have a ObservableCollection

```
public class Viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Lib.Number> numbers = new()
    {
        // Some Debugdata
        new Lib.Number(1),
        new Lib.Number(3),
        new Lib.Number(5),
        new Lib.Number(2),
        new Lib.Number(6)
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Lib.Number> Numbers {
        get { return numbers; }
        set { numbers = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public Viewmodel()
    {
        Numbers.CollectionChanged += RefreshCheck;
    }

    private void RefreshCheck(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Check();
    }

    public void Check()
    {
        Lib.Model.CheckNumbers(ref numbers);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
        else PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

in my Model

```
public static class Model
    {
        public static bool CheckNumbers(ref ObservableCollection<Number> numbers)
        {
            List<Exception> exception = new();

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                Number number = numbers[i];
                Exception? result = CheckNumber(ref number, numbers);
                numbers[i] = number; //line that create the exception

                if(result != null) exception.Add(result);
            }

            if( exception.Any() == true) return false;
            else return true;
        }

        public static Exception? CheckNumber(ref Number number, ObservableCollection<Number> numbers)
        {
            Exception? error = null;

            Number num = number;
            if(numbers != null && numbers.Any() == true)
            {
                if (numbers.Where(item => item.Digit == (num.Digit + 1)).Any() == true)
                    number.HasSuccessor = true;
                else if (numbers.MaxBy(item => item.Digit).Digit == num.Digit)
                    number.HasSuccessor = true;
                else if (numbers.MinBy(item => item.Digit).Digit == num.Digit)
                    number.HasSuccessor = true;
                else
                    number.HasSuccessor = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Exception exception = new ("numbers was null");
            }

            return error;
        }
    }
```

So, let say the user submit 1 ,3 ,5, 2, 6 -> with 4 missing. I will show him errormarks at number 5,6. but he can decide to delete 1,2,3 and import 5,6 because they now valid.

I can force the user to press button after change if items or create a "fire & forget" task that just wait a few milliseconds before starting to recheck, but I think that are not clean solutions...
Maybe something like a transaction in a database with stop the change-event till i finish the changes...

Anyone a hint or link for me?

Comment: get rid of the line which throws exception (`numbers[i] = number;`) it is very suspicious, because `numbers[i] == number` should be `true`, unless CheckNumber changes `number` reference which is much more suspicious

Comment: Funny how you show a lot of less interesting code and when it gets to the interesting part (where the error occurred) you suddenly decide to save characters and become thrifty. Assuming that you are using `ref` parameters with a purpose, I guess you are replacing instances of Number with new instances. This seems to be redundant as Number is a mutable object. Anyway, don't add or remove items from the collection. Just mutate the existing instances. I really wonder, why would you create a new instance instead of simply setting the boolean property to true?

Comment: Number even implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Remove all the `ref` key words from your code. They don't make sense.

Comment: @ASh I add more code from ConsoleApp where I put the code I showed here in, maybe it make some things more clear. As you see not change the item in the collection. In `CheckNumber` I change item given my caller function and so i need to replace the item in the collection with the changed item.

@BionicCode I removed ref, but it does not change anything. Number implements it to, because before the DataGrid does not recognise changes in the properties. Also hope the "interesting" code is now in... ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot folks!!!

The ref I had because I still have the words from my friend in mind "functions get a copy of the value, if you want to get the change, use ref or return the new value".
Now I remove all refs change some of the code that copy the object and put them back in the collection after change and now everything works as expected...

Saved my day! :-)

Comment: This is not how it is. C# has value types and reference types. In case of a value types like a struct, the value (memory location) is copied indeed. But with reference types the reference to the same memory location is copied. This means modifying the reference copy also modifies the "original" reference as both references point to the same memory.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly copy objects and put them back into the collection! Simply change the property of the object. As you are operating on the same memory object, the items in the collection will reflect the value. ref hower allows to pass the original reference instead of a copy. This is usefulk if you want to make the reference point to a new memory object. I highly recommend to lookup the difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the collection during a `CollectionChanged` event.

You don't need the ref parameters. `Number` is a reference type and therefore changing it's values outside the collection does also change the object in the collection.
It's a reference type, which means the *reference* is copied and not the value (memory location). Although the references are not equal, they still point to the same memory location. Thus both references, original and copy, modify the *same* memory location i.e. same object instance.

**Example**

```cs
public static void Main()
{
  var person = new Person() { Age = 20 };
  person.Age = 30;
  Console.WriteLine(Person.Age); // Age == 30

  ChangeAgeTo100(person);
  Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // Age == 100

  ChangePersonInstance(person, 50);
  Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // Age == 100

  ChangePersonInstanceRef(ref person, 50);
  Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // Age == 50
}

private void ChangeAgeTo100(Person person)
{
  person.Age = 100;
}

private void ChangePersonInstance(Person person, int newAge)
{
  person = new Person() { Age = newAge };
}

private void ChangePersonInstanceRef(ref Person person, int newAge)
{
  person = new Person() { Age = newAge };
}
```

Furthermore, you should not pass around `Exception` objects. Exceptions must be thrown using the throw keyword. In case of argument or null reference exceptions you want the application to crash, so that the developer can fix his code. The exception message will show the exact line of code that has thrown the exception.

The following code is a fixed and improved/simplified version of your critical code section:

```cs
// Will throw an exception in case the numbers collection is null or empty
public static void CheckNumbers(ObservableCollection<Number> numbers)
{
  foreach (Number number in numbers)
  {
    CheckNumber(number, numbers);  
  }
}

public static void CheckNumber(Number number, ObservableCollection<Number> numbers)
{
  if (numbers == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(numbers));
  }

  if (!numbers.Any())
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Collection is empty", nameof(numbers));
  }
        
  number.HasSuccessor = 
    numbers.Any(item => item.Digit == number.Digit + 1)
      || numbers.Max(item => item.Digit) == number.Digit
      || numbers.Min(item => item.Digit) == number.Digit;
}
```

Also, because you are using the null-conditional operator `?.` the explicit null check in `OnPropertyChanged` is redundant:

```cs
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```